# eclipse can not recognise my layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i downloaded zxing library and installed it on my device. now i tried to make a simple app the extends zxing library. in this simple app I created a new layout for it and when i tried to setmycontentview to be this layout, eclipse highlits it with red and when i move the mouse pointer on the highlighted layout, eclipse suggests the following:

1-create the field "activity_firstactivity" in type layout
OR
2-create constant "activity_firstactivity" in type layout

now, my question is:why eclipse can not reach my xml file for this layout, i created the layout inside the layout folder but eclipse can't recognise it.

UPDATE:
even when i press ctrl+space the layout name is not listed

Java Code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstactivity);
```

Comment: but do you have the .java file of the layout?

Comment: no, there is the XML file and the .JAVA file, have you got both?

Comment: Can you post your code? Have you tried cleaning the project?

Comment: i posted the code and i cleaned the project

Comment: do as Rajesh said, clean the project and restart eclipse then it might work (refreshing program).

Comment: Pharoah.  Have you rebuilt your project.  Or forced r.java to be regenerated?    Alexandre F.  There is NO Java file for a layout.

Comment: i did as Rajesh suggested but the problem still exist

Comment: Confirm that you haven't made any typing errors when naming the file and that its name is *exactly* `activity_firstactivity.xml`

Comment: yes i confirm no typing errors

Comment: even when i press ctrl+space the layout name is not listed

Comment: Have you imported any other `R` class files such as `android.R` or others?

Comment: OK, try commenting out the lines for any `R` class files then clean and build the project again and see what happens.

Comment: now eclipse highlights the R and suggest to import R android

Comment: OK. If you ever need to use the `android.R` class resources then all you need to do is use them in a fully-qualified way. For example, for a list item you would specify `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Comment: now after using setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_firstactivity); eclipse highkights activity_firstactivity as not existed

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Your `activity_firstactivity` resource id is part of your project's own `R.java` class and you should be able to use `R.layout.activity_firstactivity` without any problems. What I meant is that if you need to use anything in `android.R` specify it fully-qualified. If eclipse is highlighting your own layout resource id and suggesting importing `android.R` then your layout can't be in the right place. Make sure it is in `/res/layout`

Comment: i ckecked again. the layout is layout folder whic is located inside the res folder

Answer (score 0):

probably Eclipse is trying to find the layout in the android package. Try to access your layout through the full name of your package:

```
your.package.name.R.layout.activity_firstactivity
```

Comment: do u mean like this:setContentView(com.examples.FirstActivity.R.layout.activity_firstactivity);